# Using Maven the fastest way for running and debugging

Tags: android, debugging, maven, adt

I'm quite new to Maven.

Before using Maven, I had only two main single click buttons (and keys) that I've used: run and debug. Of course I have others, but those are things that I use a lot.

Now that I need to use Maven, I use some special commands. For updating the dependencies, compiling and running on the device/emulator, I use:

```
clean install android:deploy android:run
```

However, this also uninstalls the previous app.

For debugging, sadly I do what is written [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Debug) (which doesn't allow debugging from the beginning, plus it has many more steps), or use [Debug.waitForDebugger()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#waitForDebugger%28%29) (which requires me to change to code each time for toggling run and debug modes).

How can I have the same functionality of running and debuggsing as the normal ADT plugin?

Edit: about the uninstallation issue, the answer would be to set undeployBeforeDeploy to false instead of true.

Comment: Do you use Eclipse or IntelliJ?

Comment: i use eclipse. does it matter?

Comment: The first link you referred is two years old, many things have been changed significantly since then, include android SDK/ADT, android-maven-plugin, m2e and m2e-android. I don't have any problem using Eclipse's run/debug buttons on my mavenized android project.

Comment: i see , but they didn't update the links ... anyway , what should i do for both of them (run & debug) ?

Comment: Once your mavenized android project is properly imported into Eclipse, do whatever you normally do for running/debugging in Eclipse. AFAIK, maven and android eclipse plugin are not mutually exclusive, at least in current version.

Comment: bit if libraries are being used inside maven , so that eclipse won't need to have them in the workspace , it won't be able to get them, no ? it gives me weird errors such as "Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/hamcrest/Description; onversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/hamcrest/Description; "

Comment: maybe the problems are because of the pom.xml file?

Comment: ok , for the uninstallation "bug" , it's because for some reason i had undeployBeforeDeploy set to true instead of false . however , i still want an easy way to debug.